"Data is too long" error when deploying Flask server to Vercel
I am getting the following error when I try to deploy a Flask server to Vercel:
Failed to process build result for "api/detect.py". Data: {"type":"Lambda"}.
Error: data is too long

My server file, detect.py, is in a directory called api. The error started appearing when I created a requirements.txt file to install dependencies that I need. I am running a yolov8 model to process images. Here is what is in my requirements.txt file:
Flask==3.0.3
flask_cors==4.0.1
werkzeug==3.0.2
pillow==10.2.0
ultralytics==8.2.71
python-dotenv==1.0.1
numpy==1.26.4

I found this discussion that talks about the issue and how the size of the dependencies may be the problem. Is there some workaround for Vercel? I would still like to use it for my project.
I tried to do the following in my vercel.json file at the root of the project to see if I can maybe increase the allowed storage size but it resulted in the same error:
  {
    "src": "api/detect.py",
    "use": "@vercel/python",
    "config": {
      "maxLambdaSize": "2000mb"
    }
  }


same issue here
